# Protect all routes with Rack::Auth::Basic

Tags: rack, http-authentication

I have a simple admin app that I'd like protected by basic HTTP auth. Here's what I have in my config.ru. This doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic do |user, pass|
  pass == ENV['ADMIN_PASS']
end

run Rack::URLMap.new(
  '/' => Rack::File.new('./public/index.html')
  '/resque' => Resque::Server.new,
  '/mongo' => Genghis::Server.new
)
```

Comment: Could it be that your browser is caching the auth headers? Try changing the ENV['ADMIN_PASS'] and that should kick you the login prompt.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that. Also tried in different browsers with clean caches. No dice.

Comment: What Rack server are you trying this on? Just tried it in Shotgun, Unicorn, and Thin and they all seemed OK!

Comment: Hmm weird. Trying out in dev with pow. Doesn't work with pow. But any other server seems fine. Guess it's a pow issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rack::Auth::Basic expects a admin/password array, so you could do something like:

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
    [username, password] == [ 'admin', ENV['ADMIN_PASS'] ]
end
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm never prompted for the user/pass.